# Using pdb with import in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might just be learning pains from migrating from Python2 to Python3 but when I am developing a module and deploying it, I often find myself debugging the initialization of that module in the command line or IDLE with something akin to:

```
import pdb
pdb.run("import mymodule")
```

When I do this in Python2, since it is a builtin function, I step into the debugger and start to go through my file. In Python3, since import now redirects to the importlib module, the _bootstrap file of the importlib module always shows itself a frozen so I cannot see where pdb is in the code. The only way that I have found to assure that I get into the code of my module is to put a `pdb.set_trace()` in my module, which I would prefer not to do. Is there a way to get into my module without using `set_trace`?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` as the first line in your module?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything strictly wrong with using it, it's just not a habit that I have and I would prefer a way that wouldn't require me to add and remove a line from my module while I'm working with it. I write and maintain a number of modules that wrap external libraries so stepping into them when I have them deployed on a production system  and dealing with dll hell on Windows is a very common thing for me to do.